# Android Studio Custom ListView with Images lagging when scrolling

Tags: java, android, performance, listview

I'm searching for 2 days now for a fix but I dont find one

may you can help me
that is what I have now:
I'm not downloading the images from a server or something

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_products, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.textView_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
            holder.textView_description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_description);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[position]);
        holder.textView_name.setText(NAMES[position]);
        holder.textView_description.setText(DESCRIPTIONS[position]);

        return view;

    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView_name;
    public TextView textView_description;
}
```

}

Comment: what is IMAGES[position]?

Comment: no im not should I?

Comment: It is a array: `static int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.shirt, R.drawable.sweater, R.drawable.bag,
            R.drawable.day, R.drawable.week, R.drawable.month,
            R.drawable.dayorange, R.drawable.weekorange, R.drawable.monthorange,
            R.drawable.dayred, R.drawable.weekred, R.drawable.monthred};`

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: It is lagging, and I now what you meant

Comment: Are you using any `Looper`? and what are the resolution of your images?

Comment: No im not and they re 512x512

Comment: I think *512 x 512* is too big for `ListView`, use *312 x 312* resources!

Comment: Ok i will try it

Comment: Omg it worked the pictures were to big hahah

Comment: Please use any image loader library out there. Example is Picasso or Fresco. Your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Picasso` library for loading image in android.
`Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);`
https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using ListView if either especially dealing with images or large content. For this purpose [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) was created.

Also make sure your application main thread is free from heavy tasks(disk,network,large images drawing,etc). Enable [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to get the point.